# Django LEFT JOIN, efficiently?

Tags: sql, django, left-join

Suppose I have this model:

```
class PhotoAlbum(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Photo(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey('PhotoAlbum')
```

And I want to do this query: "Find 10 albums whose name starts with 'The', and then give me all the photos in those albums."

In SQL I could do it something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT * FROM photoalbum WHERE title LIKE 'The%' LIMIT 10) AS selected_albums
LEFT JOIN photo ON photo.album_id = selected_albums.id
```

My question is, how can I do this in Django? ***(WITHOUT TRIGGERING A QUERY FOR EACH ALBUM!)*** I assume this is a fairly common requirement, and I can't believe there isn't some way to do it.

If there is no Django-ey way, I will settle for "how can I implement this in Django using raw SQL?".

Here are some things which will not work:

- `select_related()`; that is for *forward* `ForeignKey` relationships, this is backwards.
- <del>`prefetch_related()`; also for forward relationships.</del> Edit: Actually this *does* work! At least for one level of `ForeignKey`s.
- `PhotoAlbum.photo_set`; that triggers a query for each album.
- The closest I have got is:

  albums = PhotoAlbum.objects.all()[:10]
  photos = Photo.objects.filter(album__in=albums)

But it doesn't work on MySQL sadly, and I've been told it is better to use `LEFT JOIN`'s than the `WHERE ... IN (SELECT ...)` type query that this creates.

## Edit

I found a [3 year old mailing list post about the problem](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/django-users/9R_FoydInh0). No solution therein.

A [6 year old bug report saying they won't fix it](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/2238). No reason given other than "that's not how it works". Apparently it is possible in RoR though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work and only do two queries. prefetch_related works for reverse FKs, that's actually what it was created for:

```
for album in PhotoAlbum.objects.filter(title__startswith='The').prefetch_related('photo_set')[:10]:
    print album.photo_set.all()
```

Comment: This works! It uses `WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)` instead of `LEFT JOIN` but fair enough. Now I want to chain `prefetch_related()` to two levels of reverse `ForeignKey`s, but I'll leave that for another time. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

In Django 1.4+ you can use [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related):

```
PhotoAlbum.objects.filter(title__startswith='The').prefetch_related('photo')[:10]
```

In lesser versions try [django-batch-select](https://github.com/lilspikey/django-batch-select/).

**UPDATE**

Sorry. I'm still on 1.3 primarily, so I don't use `prefetch_related` much. In every other query type, you don't include the `_set` appendix, but Django apparently broke convention here. It'll work if you use `prefetch_related('photo_set')`.

If you need to fetch multiple things, you can list the fields just like you would with `select_related`, i.e.:

```
prefetch_related('something', 'something_else', 'foo')
```

But pay close attention to this part from the docs:

> Also remember that, as always with QuerySets, any subsequent chained methods which imply a different database query will ignore previously cached results, and retrieve data using a fresh database query. So, if you write the following:
>
> ```
>    >>> pizzas = Pizza.objects.prefetch_related('toppings')
>    >>> [list(pizza.toppings.filter(spicy=True)) for pizza in pizzas]
> ```
>
> ...then the fact that pizza.toppings.all() has been prefetched will not help you - in fact it hurts performance, since you have done a database query that you haven't used. So use this feature with caution!

Comment: And then I use `PhotoAlbum.photo_set` and it won't trigger a query? Can I also chain `prefetch_related()`'s so if I had a three-level tree (e.g. also a `Bookcase` table that contained `PhotoAlbum`s) I could do `Bookcase.objects.filter(madefrom='Mahogany').prefetch_related('photoalbum').filter(title__startswith='The').prefetch_Related('photo')[:10]` and it would get all the photos for all books starting with "The" in the first 10 mahogany bookcases? Also, I note that `prefetch_related()` does the join in python. What if I have a billion photos?

Comment: Also, your code doesn't actually work because `photo` isn't a field of `PhotoAlbum`. It seems `prefetch_related()` only works with forward relations too.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to trigger a photo_set on all PhotoAlbums, yes? Just the specified ones?

```
for p in PhotoAlbum.objects.filter(title__startswith='The'):
    p.photo_set.all()
```

Comment: If 100 albums start with "The" this will still do 100 queries, right?