# prefetch_related doesn't cache

Tags: django, django-models

I am simply stumped. I'm trying to implement a textbook case of `prefect_related` in my django app, but it simply won't work. Here are the relevant models:

```
class CanUseUnit(models.Model):

  objects = UnitManager()

  ingredient = models.ForeignKey('Ingredient', db_column='ingredient', related_name='useable_units')
  unit = models.ForeignKey('Unit', related_name='used_by', db_column='unit', limit_choices_to=models.Q(parent_unit__exact=None))
```

Please note that although this model has a custom Manager, this is a simple subclass of `models.Managar` with only 1 method named `get_all_info()`, so I don't think that has anything to do with my problem:

I'm trying to query all Ingredients, and prefetch their useable units. This is my Django query:

```
def list_ingredients(request):
  ingredients = Ingredient.objects.all().order_by('accepted', 'name').prefetch_related('useable_units')
  for ingredient in ingredients:
    print(ingredient.useable_units.all())

  return render(request, 'admin/list_ingredients.html', {'ingredients': ingredients})
```

But Django seems to hit the database on every `print` statement... What is going on?

EDIT:

It seems that the caching does work when called from a template. When I leave out the print statement in the view above, and visit the page containing following template code:

```
{% for ingredient in ingredients %}
<tr>
  <td><a href="/ingredients/edit/{{ ingredient.id }}/">{{ ingredient.name }}</a></td>
  <td align="center">{{ ingredient.useable_units.count }}</td>
</tr>

{% endfor %}
```

The database is only getting hit twice (which I would expect, once for Ingredients, and once for the prefetch_related).

SOLVED:
Well, the problem seemed to have resolved itself... I kept trying and restarting the test server, and suddenly it stopped querying for every Ingredient. Not sure what happened, but I'm glad its resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. Schacki's answer was wrong, and prefetch related does indeed only require 2 queries instead of one for every ingredient.

My error was in a different part of the template, where I was displaying the properties of the intermediate model.

So what I should have done was the following:

```
ingredients = Ingredient.objects.all().order_by('accepted', 'name').prefetch_related('canuseunit_set')
```

instead of:

```
ingredients = Ingredient.objects.all().order_by('accepted', 'name').prefetch_related('useable_units')
```

Answer (score -2):

If you look at the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related, it says that

> prefetch_related, on the other hand, does a separate lookup for each relationship, and does the ‘joining’ in Python

From my understanding, this is exactly, what you see.

Comment: Well, I found a previous SO question, where from the accepted answer, I was led to believe that it would only do 2 queries (not 1 for every Ingredient): [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746229/django-left-join-efficiently) But if this is not the case, is there no way to do a batch prefetch_related?

Comment: There seems to be a misunderstanding, relation is the ForeignKey relationship, so "for each relationship" means for every ForeignKey, OneToOne, ManyToMany, etc. So yes, it's only 2 in your case, but what he's posted is also correct. It doesn't answer your question, but it isn't factually wrong either.